# Plugins not working in onDeviceReady for iOS

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I created a cordova project via this [tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/develop/1-embed-webview/ios/).

It works, but when I try to install a plugin (using the prescribed method in the tutorial), it doesn't enable the JS api of the plugin.

Example: I install cordova-plugin-device, and the window.device in JS doesn't do anything when the app is run through Xcode.

Here is the app HTML with all the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Homeschool Mapper</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

These are the commands I did when creating the project:

```
cordova-ios/bin/create app com.swordhiltstudios.homeschoolmapper Homeschool\ Mapper
cd app
plugman install --platform ios --project . --plugin cordova-plugin-dialogs
plugman install --platform ios --project . --plugin cordova-plugin-device
plugman install --platform ios --project . --plugin cordova-plugin-local-notifications
```

After those commands, I set up the [storyboard in Xcode](http://docs.phonegap.com/develop/1-embed-webview/ios/#lesson-2-set-up-the-storyboard).

#### Xcode output

> ```
> 2015-12-30 10:00:53.440 Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.0.1 is starting. 2015-12-30
> ```
>
> 10:00:53.444 Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233] Multi-tasking -> Device:
>   YES, App: YES 2015-12-30 10:00:53.509 Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233]
>   Apache Cordova native platform version 4.0.1 is starting. 2015-12-30
>   10:00:53.510 Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233] Multi-tasking -> Device:
>   YES, App: YES 2015-12-30 10:00:53.523 Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233]
>
> ```
> Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful. Your application might be rejected by Apple if you store too much data. For more
> ```
>
> information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" at:
>   https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/ To
>   disable web storage backup to iCloud, set the BackupWebStorage
>   preference to "local" in the Cordova config.xml file
>
> ```
> 2015-12-30 10:00:53.850 Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233] Using UIWebView 2015-12-30 10:00:53.861 Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233]
> ```
>
> [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.887990ms 2015-12-30 10:00:53.874
>   Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter]
>       11.270046ms 2015-12-30 10:00:53.877 Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.805974ms 2015-12-30 10:00:53.881
>   Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233] [CDVTimer][localnotification]
>       3.884017ms 2015-12-30 10:00:53.882 Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233] [CDVTimer][localnotification] 0.041008ms 2015-12-30 10:00:53.883
>   Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup]
>       23.401022ms 2015-12-30 10:00:55.530 Homeschool Mapper[1229:501233] Resetting plugins due to page load. 2015-12-30 10:00:55.895 Homeschool
>   Mapper[1229:501233] Finished load of:
>   file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/4FB0A5E5-9CB0-49CD-9113-310A665B0C80/Homeschool%20Mapper.app/www/index.html

#### Update:

When I don't put the device plugin in the `onDeviceReady`, and just execute the following, it works; so it seems like an issue directly related to the plugin, and not Cordova proper:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
    element.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(['hello']);
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that we don't have a reproducible set of code that shows what isn't working that's supposed to.  Depending on which version of cordova you're using, the window.device.plugins moved to another namespace, IIRC.

Comment: I used this Cordova: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios and there hasn't been a commit since I downloaded it.

Comment: No plugin whatsoever works. I just put cordova-plugin-device as an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99317/discussion-between-andrew-mast-and-george-stocker).